# Can anyone recommend a DataMatrix decoding library?

Tags: .net, barcode

My .NET application needs to decode 2D bar codes in DataMatrix format.

I originally used a commercial library called Tasman.Bars, which had great royalty-free licensing terms, awesome performance, and supported many different bar code types... except that on certain images it would crash. These images were very rare, but this was still a show-stopping bug. Unfortunately, by the time I ran into it, the library was no longer sold or supported, having been bought out by another company and replaced with a much more expensive product.

I've tried the open-source libdmtx, both the native version (via a wrapper) and the .NET port (DataMatrix.net), and its performance is disappointing. I have to give it a timeout value when it decodes, and 1 second isn't long enough to decode some images even on a 2.8 GHz quad-core. 4 seconds works better, but that's an irritating amount of time, and even 10 seconds is insufficient for one image I've tried - I suspect it's just failing completely on that one, even though it looks visually identical to another one that works.

So... any recommendations? Commercial libraries are fine as long as the royalties are low or nonexistent.

Answer (score 1):

Zebra Crossing ( http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ ) has a partial port to C#, and I believe Data Matrix is implemented. Check out http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/csharp/datamatrix/
 and see for yourself.
Please let me know how it turns out.

Comment: zxing's DataMatrix support is "alpha quality" and posts on the mailing list claim that the detector module is unreliable. I will be using this in a commercial product that needs to be pretty solid.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good discussion. I have a couple (hopefully helpful) comments to add:

@godsky: Regarding the AIPSYS library, in 2008 I detected the presence of libdmtx symbols in their demo binaries, strongly suggesting that they simply obfuscated the code, added some pieces, and started charging hundreds of dollars for it. I notified AIPSYS of the probable LGPL violation but they never responded. Since AIPSYS is a Chinese company I didn't know how to pursue it beyond this other than logging a complaint at gpl-violations.org.

@Jesse: The current versions of libdmtx often need some tuning to get optimal performance. I have heard reports of images taking multiple seconds to scan, but I can rarely reproduce it locally. If you still have any of these problem images sitting around I would love to scan a few to see if I can reproduce the problem (and possibly help you in the process). We have a new version in the works that will perform better "out of the box", but for now it still needs a little lovin' to achieve the best results.

Disclaimer: Even if your images scan quickly using native libdmtx I can't predict how that will translate to libdmtx-net (the wrapper) or DataMatrix.net (the .NET port) since I wasn't involved in those efforts. But hopefully it would provide a start.